# Alter column size throws dependency errors in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a windows 8 machine with Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) installed.

On my database:

```
alter table myAddress
alter column myTown nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
```

When I run the above query on this machine, to alter a column size, where existing column size is **50**, the query works fine without any error.

Now, I have another windows 10 machine with Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) installed.

When I run the same above query on this windows 10 machine, I get below errors:

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The object 'defEmptyString' is dependent on column 'myTown'.
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The index 'IX_myAddress_Name_Town' is dependent on column 'myTown'.
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The index 'IX_myAddress_Town' is dependent on column 'myTown'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 5
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN myTown failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

I Installed SQL server 2017 database instance initially and came across this issue, so then I installed 2016 database instance, but I am still getting the same error. Any thoughts?

I can't change the query as it is an old script, part of a big script that creates database and everyone in the team uses it. There must be something different in the configuration of my new windows 10 machine.
Any ideas would help from you all experts.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I think I have managed to reproduce it. The collation of the column is set with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e04f2572305efd5337cb47bc6af419b

Comment: This means that in the first case there were no indexes with this column participation

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with any version of SQL Server unless I am trying to reduce the maximum length of the data type, rather than increase it - http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=620b4133a9901d89ecca390f990c27a1 Or when changing the type from varchar to nvarchar http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9b9bff314dffabfa38e29ac3fdc6d708

Comment: Maybe his initial type vas not nvarchar but varchar?

Comment: did you try to drop defEmptyString and the two indexes, perform the alter table and then recreate the items?

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue on windows10 Sql 2016 SP1 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the response. Meanwhile I have been working on changing the collation of the server from sql_latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS to Latin1_General_CI_AS(matching collation with the database). Restarted the sql server from management studio and now it works.

I think I have managed to reproduce it. The collation of the column is set with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Reproduced:
http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e04f2572305efd5337cb47bc6af419b

Solution:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3519/changing-sql-server-collation-after-installation/

1. STOP SQLServer service from windows services
2. run sqlservr -m -T4022 -T3659 -s"SQLEXP2014" -q"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI"